# How to keep showing a bookmark button when text is entered?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm currently struggling with `UISearchController` in Swift.
I'd like to keep showing a bookmark button when text is entered into a textField.

I need to take the text via a bookmark button (or any other ways that may exist) other than via "searchBarSearchButtonClicked" method called when search is executed.

However, the button is hidden once text is entered, as a clear button is shown over it.

I set the following option to ".never", which unfortunately didn't show a bookmark button although a clear button disappeared.

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = .never
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to resolve the issue and make it work?

I suppose it's the specifications of UISearchController.
If not, I'd appreciate it if you could tell me some alternative ways.

For your reference, my code and screen images are below.

| Before entering text | After entering text |
| --- | --- |
| [image: image before entering text] | [image: image after entering text] |

**Properties:**

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

**setupSearchController:**
I set up a bookmark button and clear button in the method below.

```
private func setupSearchController() {
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    definesPresentationContext = true

    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search channels"

    // bookmark and clear button settings
    searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = .never
    searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
    searchController.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "globe"), for: .bookmark, state: .normal)
}
```

**searchBarSearchButtonClicked:**
Search process is executed in the method below.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("searchBarSearchButtonClicked")
    print("keyword", searchBar.text ?? "Empty keyword")
    guard let keyword = searchBar.text else {
        print("Keyword is empty")
        return
    }
    // Search process is here...
}
```

**searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked:**
I'd like to execute another process (NOT search process) using entered text in the method below.

```
func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("Bookmark button is clicked...")
    guard let searchQuery = searchBar.text, !searchQuery.isEmpty else {
        print("Keyword is empty")
        return
    }
    // Another process is here...
}
```

If you have some additional information you need, please let me know.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Your question is very good for a first question. Just some formatting tips: Instead of `<br />`, just hit return 2 times. Also don't use the `>` in front of code, wrap it inside ```your code here```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I edited another question I posted a few minutes ago too. I'm happy if you give me some advice about questions I have.

Comment: Any luck with the solution to the issue?

Comment: Found a solution: searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
Make sure this is not made false anywhere in the code or in the updateSearchResults function based on whether the searchbar is active or not.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for bookmark not seen problem:

```
searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
```

Make sure this is not made false anywhere in the code or in the updateSearchResults function based on whether the searchbar is active or not.

Comment: "this article" link is broken

Comment: Removed the broken link. @Steven Grosmark

Comment: The OP already has this in their code and it doesn't work for them.